# Adding numbers from 3 different CSV columns

Tags: c, csv

I am newer to programming and I am trying to figure out how I can add all of the numbers from the B column together and all of the C column together and the D column together with those variables named x y and z respectively. I have been searching everywhere for an answer. All I have gotten is to read the first line of the csv file.

This is a screenshot of part of the CSV file:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be in C? Excel would do that better and easier.

Comment: It does have to be in C. I am struggling with how I get the numbers into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read it in, you need to somehow split it up into actual columns.  Check this function, that should help.

```
strtok()
```

Then you need to store it in some kind of array.  Then index which elements in the array you want, and process them by using a cumulative sum.   This might require a while loop until you've reached the last line of the file.

I will leave the actual code to you, but this should get you going.

Comment: Keep in mind that CSV files can look like 1234, "Smith, Jr.", "Bud ""Buddy""" due to escaping of commas, quotes and possibly newline data.

Comment: However, the OPs screenshot indicates they are all doubles.  So most likely they will not need to deal with quoted column types, but a good reminder.

Comment: Yes they are all doubles in the CSV file. Thanks for your response ergonaut and I will research that strtok() function more